# can I test a mixed levels model with only some levels of a predictor to explore interactions?

Tags: r, mixed-model, interaction, multilevel-analysis

I have this data frame

```
subject <- factor(rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),each=12))
dep <- c(0.3763244126,0.2185001692,0.4191841742,0.9812978664,0.7429273683,0.6254715486,0.6200958213,0.4693300191,0.1779032899,0.0035873980,0.8821949826,0.4818012617,0.0008013437,0.6280700732,0.7126500814,0.4984349359,0.2457996449,0.3085733312,0.5903398243,0.3704800352,0.8215325437,0.0445236221,0.1849731791,0.3670945817,0.0022268933,0.1630332691,0.9734050406,0.2638539758,0.8550054496,0.9413964085,0.4548943471,0.0440815873,0.5222098769,0.6553600784,0.6853486744,0.0571945074,0.0923124240,0.6976544929,0.9257440316,0.5658967043,0.0636543627,0.1038574059,0.0662497468,0.9165439918,0.5200087291,0.9528015053,0.5347318368,0.1848373057,0.9948602219,0.9633110918,0.1482162909,0.9000614029,0.0898618386,0.7975253051,0.8334557347,0.8629821099,0.0001795699,0.2488384889,0.6382902598,0.1103540359,0.2199716354,0.2737281912,0.5694398067,0.7940423761,0.4906677457,0.5191186895,0.4770589883,0.2823238128,0.2458788699,0.6363522802,0.0306954833,0.6979198116)

f1 <- factor(rep(c("Female","Male","Female","Male","Male","Female"), each=12))
f2 <- c(0.098788608,0.934606288,0.145045152,0.841969882,0.498234471,0.562897249,0.359740488,0.082046687,0.183987342,0.082418820,0.173424633,0.799291329,0.041450568,0.686708743,0.352092230,0.823550310,0.650857094,0.331705763,0.659111451,0.745187314,0.066165065,0.870759966,0.154977488,0.031703774,0.065251788,0.707452073,0.564604314,0.224798417,0.656363138,0.047954841,0.500513114,0.923316812,0.706629266,0.561530974,0.670860932,0.414969178,0.709973062,0.452946384,0.187624344,0.278656351,0.562138433,0.655193272,0.014868182,0.518697012,0.414113229,0.273464316,0.844080831,0.962636550,0.952739605,0.728627219,0.761122951,0.309977150,0.755239042,0.208627128,0.481429897,0.376021223,0.753871400,0.164842337,0.921081061,0.859677311,0.600462073,0.119193708,0.276722102,0.854752641,0.962710853,0.956277061,0.228313179,0.920405764,0.001594131,0.104930433,0.241548888,0.549643015)
f3 <- factor(rep(c("day1","day2","day3","day4"),each=3, times=6))

data <- data.frame(sub=subject, dep=dep, f1=f1, f2=f2, f3=f3)

m <- lmer(dep ~ f1*f2*f3 + (1|sub), data=data)
```

This is random data so nothing is significant, but let's say the `f1*f3` interaction is significant, and I wish to explore if the interaction results from differences from `day1` to `day2`, or `day2` to `day3` and so on.

My first thought was to create a new model with just the two levels of `f3` I'm interested in

```
data2 <- dplyr::filter(data, f3 == "day1" | f3 == "day2")
m1 <- lmer(dep ~ f1*f2*f3 + (1|sub), data=data2)

data2 <- dplyr::filter(data, f3 == "day2" | f3 == "day3")
m2 <- lmer(dep ~ f1*f2*f3 + (1|sub), data=data2)

data2 <- dplyr::filter(data, f3 == "day3" | f3 == "day4")
m3 <- lmer(dep ~ f1*f2*f3 + (1|sub), data=data2)
```

If only `m1` is significant, can I say that the difference from `day1` to `day2` is likely what's causing the `f1*f3` interaction I saw in the original model `m`? Is this a valid interpretation of the `f1*f3` interaction?

Comment: I would say no to your last 3 models. The tests you mentioned can perform on the first model, although I am not clear what "if the interaction results from differences from day1 to day2, or day2 to day3 and so on." means.

Comment: Thanks @a_statistician. What I meant was that I'd like to test whether the `f1*f3` interaction is due to, for example a larger difference from `day1` to `day2` in males relative to females but perhaps no differences in gender in the other days, which would cause the `f1*f3` interaction. Why would the last 3 models be incorrect? This was suggested to me in another post. How would you test where this interaction is coming from using only the first model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the interaction $f1*f3$ is significant. You want to test the null hypothesis that the difference between day 1 and day 2 are the same among male and female.

Suppose dummy variables are defined as: $X_1 = 0$ for male and $=1$ for female. $X_2=0, X_3 = 0$ for day 1 $X_2=1, X_3 = 0$ for day 2 $X_2=0, X_3 = 1$ for day 2

Then the fixed effect part for gender and day is:

$$p(gender,day)=\beta_1X_1+\beta_2X_2+\beta_3X_3+\beta_4X_1X_2+\beta_5X_1X_3$$

For male at day 1, $p(male,day 1) = 0$, $p(male, day 2)= \beta_2$, $p(female, day 1) = \beta_1$, and $p(female, day 2) = \beta_1 + \beta_2 + \beta_4$.

Your null hypothesis is p(male, day 1) - p(male, day 2) = p(female, day 1) - p(female, day 2). In terms of $\beta$, it is $H_o: \beta_4 = 0$. So after fitting that large model, you can test this null hypothesis.

For the last 3 small models, you exclude some observations. These observations may be not useful for fixed effects, but they contribute their residuals, which are useful for random effects, variance-covariance estimate.

Comment: Thanks @a_statistician for your answer. Unfortunately I'm still not sure how to transform that into code that I can use in R... I'm not a statistician and I've just started to learn mixed-models. Could you give an example how you would translate that into R code please?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know R. I work with SAS for many years. Basically, the null hypothesis can be written in the form $L\beta = 0$. Then input $L$ into the software and you will get the test. In your case, $L=(0,0,0,1,0,,,)$ In SAS, use estimate statement. In R, you may search for test linear hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks @a_statistician, I'll try to find out how to do that in R. Many thanks for your help.